# NSAlert on top of action sheet shows "Do not show this message again"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an action sheet on top of my application main window, and then I prompt an `NSAlert`.

The `NSAlert` contains a suppression checkbox and layout ("Do not show this message again") which I did not add manually, and I'd like to remove it from the `NSAlert`.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 6):

From the docs: [`[NSAlert setShowsSuppressionButton:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAlert/setShowsSuppressionButton:)

Comment: yours is a. inaccurate and b. incomplete

Comment: you didn't specify it was a boolean and it's alert not NSAlert read the docs

Comment: @RachelGallen That's how Objective-C method selectors are written... And he links to the documentation which includes every relevant info needed. 10/10 answer, would upvote again.

Comment: Are you guaranteeing that the OP's instance of `NSAlert` is called `alert`? And since I've provided a link to the docs, I think the OP will probably be able to guess that it's a `bool`.

Comment: This solution doesn't work, I still get a checkbox with "Don't show this message again". Also, my original alert's setShowsSuppressionButton was set to "NO".